# How can I use paplay to play flac files to a PulseAudio sink?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, music-player, flac

I built a flac file with

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format flac "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn_zSyYN_0k"
```

I'm trying to play it with `paplay` but any combination I try I get static.

```
paplay -p --file-format=flac "Small Brass Dinner Bell-kn_zSyYN_0k.flac"
```

What options should I provide to paplay to get it to play my flac file?